# Can I become a 2100+ rated player in 2 years if I train for 15 hours a day?

Tags: rating, training, elo

I’m 15 years old, and my FIDE rating is 1674. I’ve been playing chess since I was one and half years old. If I train, say, something like 15 hours a day and play in 20 tournaments, is it possbile for me to become a 2100+ rated player in 2 years?

Comment: Yes, 400 points in 2 years is do-able. I don't think it will take 15 hours a day. Find a local chess club. Get an instructor. Make sure your practice time is focused.

Comment: 15 hours a day. Are you human? :)

Comment: If you can do it 15 h a day, it isn't training … ;-)

Comment: I khow , that's why I took admission in an open school and right now since last 15 days I am working hard 10-15 hours daily. Really hard and I also played a draw against Spanish gm Oleg korneev rated 2579 in a simul at fide online arena

Comment: @TonyEnnis, I suggest you post your comment as an answer. Otherwise, I'm going to steal it.

Comment: @MXMLLN it isn't much of an answer. Steal away.

Comment: @TonyEnnis, Hopefully my answer follows the guidelines :(

Comment: Yes, but it would be a horrible waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

To predict someone's progress is very difficult. It depends on so many things: "chess talent", how you practice and train, opportunities to play tournaments (not too weak, not too strong), etc...

A couple of years ago, the author of following blog tried to become a grandmaster: http://roadtograndmaster.com/ and http://roadtograndmaster.com/?p=11

Maybe this blog can give you some information, ideas and tips. Of course, your situation is different, for instance, you are 10 years younger than the author of the blog.

Comment: What is the current FIDE rating of the author?

Comment: Currently, the author of the blog "roadtograndmaster" has a FIDE rating of 2062 (see https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=423130). Actually, in August 2014, he adjusted his goal to a FIDE rating of 2100 (see http://roadtograndmaster.com/?p=521).

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it is possible.**

However, you will see from the comments that no one thinks you should bother trying. Why do you think that is? What does your FIDE Candidate Master rating get you? Clearly, everyone should have hobbies and goals, but they should be realistic and well balanced. If you spent all your time playing chess instead of going to school, you will have a great chess rating, but be virtually unemployable. There is little money in the chess industry, either from tournaments or from tutoring.

**I stand behind your goal of attaining a Master rating, as probably most users do.** Just don't sacrifice your social life, your education, or your health to make it happen.

Here's [a great article on chess progress](http://www.convekta.com/softscho/l1/lesson_3.html). The higher your rating, the more difficult it is to progress.